# Что значит запись [....] перед каким-либо действием в C#?

Tags: c#, веб-программирование

Что значит некая запись в [....] перед каким-либо действием?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/

Comment: Приведите пример, показывающий в каком месте в коде она вам встретилась.